# Debugging on Iterator Java

Tags: java, iterator

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this problem with writing a nested Iterator class for a DoublyLinkedList.
I'm getting this error when running the test program. Can anyone spot any errors in my iterator class? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            last = current;
            E value = current.item;
            current = current.next; 
            index++;
            return value;
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: " I'm getting this error when running the test program. Can anyone spot any errors in my iterator class?" what error?

Comment: What error? Any exception? Please paste the error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" 2 3 4 5 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DLList.Deque$DoubleListIterator.next(Deque.java:51)
 at DLList.DequeApp.printDeque(DequeApp.java:42)
 at DLList.DequeApp.main(DequeApp.java:61)

Comment: How do you populate N?

Comment: @SMA add"++N" in public E next()?

Comment: is it always 0 or when the value of N changes?

Comment: @SMA N is the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Iterable you set the initial value of current to the second element (current = head.next), so when you try to print the last element you are actually already past your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
current = current.next;
```

for  the last iteration the current will be set to null as the previous instance next value is null. This might be reason when null value is read by iterator.

Comment: Can you please give more hints on a fix? I'm very confused on doublyLinkedList, thanks in advance!

Comment: paste the main method where you are invoking the method present in the doublylistiterator class

Comment: Hi Mohan, posted, please kindly take a look, thanks!

Comment: Did you get exception on adding or while removing?

Comment: I get a error straight away when I ran Main, it's asking for a N value input, I entered 5.

Comment: I could not even compile  Deque and DequeApp class shared by you.